# Is there a way to find 2 numbers that multiply to create a 3 digit number?

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to create a program where I'm creating division problems for the user. I want them all to be 3 digits. For example, 100/20=5. So I just want the dividend to be a 3 digit number that is divisible. Is there a way to create a program that can do that?

Comment: Choose two random two-digit numbers `d` and `r`. Then calculate the product `n = d * r`. Then show `n` and `d` to the user, and ask them to find `r = n / d`. Indeed `100 / 20 = 5` is equivalent to `100 = 20 * 5`.

Comment: @Stef Yes, but if the 2 digit random numbers are 99 and 50, then it'll be 4950, which is a 4 digit number, not a 3 digit one

Comment: @SavageCoder After choosing `d` define range for `r` choice between `100/d` and `1000/d`

Answer (score 0):

Well 3 digits integers are contained between 100 and 999, so you just want to check if they are divisible by some other number using the modulo operator and check if they are in the adequate range. Something like this:

```
divisor = 14
three_digits_divisible = [x for x in range(100, 999) if x % divisor == 0]
```

You can also automate it for a range of divisors by using a function that would return the list for a given divisor.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to generate positive integers a,b,c in a way that **a**/**b**=**c** and **a** is a three digit number.

That means that **a** is less than 1000, but greater or equal to 100. And also  **a**=**b** * **c**.

Choose a random one or two digit number. You can say that it is your **b**.

Now, above mentioned relations show, that **b** * **c**<1000 and **b** * **c** >= 100 (substitute **a**). When you have your **b**, you can calculate bounds for **c**.

- **c** < 1000/**b**
- **c** >= 100/**b**

Choose a random number **c** in these bounds, and your **a** is guaranteed to be a three digit number.

This will not generate every possible solution, as **b** was restricted to be 2 or 1-digit number.